# Getting error in Gatsby: TypeError: Cannot read property 'github' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Long-time WordPress dev and Gatsby/React/GraphQL rookie.

I am trying to emulate this [Gatsby Github Displayer](https://github.com/freiksenet/gatsby-github-displayer), which connects to the Github API via GraphQL and brings down information about your repos and then displays them on a page.

I'm looking to do things slightly differently and have both elements as components and then display one of those components on onto the main page of my [Gatsby website](https://andystitt.me/).

Here's [my repo](https://github.com/andystitt829/andy-stitt-gatsby-site) with the error in it.

Here's my  component:

```
import React from "react"

const RepositoryList = ({ repositories }) => (
  <div>
    {repositories.nodes.map((repository, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <h2><a href={repository.url}>{repository.name}</a></h2>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)

export default RepositoryList
```

and my  component that I want rendered on the homepage:

```
import React from "react"
import RepositoryList from "../components/repository-list"

const WebDevelopment = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>My repositories</h1>
    <RepositoryList repositories={data.github.viewer.repositories} />
  </div>
)

export default WebDevelopment

export const query = graphql`
  query RepositoriesQuery {
    github {
      viewer {
        repositories(
          privacy: PUBLIC
          affiliations: OWNER
          isFork: false
          first: 100
        ) {
          nodes {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`
```

Here's how I'm trying to render it onto the homepage:

```
import React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Headshot from "../components/headshot"
import PMIEFOldWebsite from "../components/pmief-old-website"
import PMIEFNewWebsite from "../components/pmief-new-website"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import "./mystyles.scss"
import JFedOldWebsite from "../components/jfed-old-website"
import JFedNewWebsite from "../components/jfed-new-website"
import WebDevelopment from "../components/web-development"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1>Digital Marketing Strategist<br />Front-End Web Developer</h1>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}>
      <Headshot />
    </div>
    <p>I've been in the web business for a long time. I worked in the nonprofit world for 15 years. I went from staff assistant to program administrator to accidental techie to full-fledged web developer.</p>
    <p>I'm currently a contractor at <a href="https://dudnyk.com/">Dudnyk</a> where I do front-end development on websites, email templates, and Google banner ads.</p>
    <p>I'm a developer with experience in HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript. I'm building this site on Gatsby so that I can play around with ES6 and React and start realizing the possiblities that the JAMstack offers.</p>
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h3>Project Management Institute Educational Foundation</h3>
    <p>I started as a program administrator and became the webmaster, email, and social media guy. I served as the staff technical expert and content manager for the rebranding and website redesign and migration from flat HTML files to Sitecore CMS.</p>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column">
          <h3>Before</h3>
          <PMIEFOldWebsite />
        </div>
        <div className="column">
          <h3>After</h3>
          <PMIEFNewWebsite />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 style={{  marginTop: `3.45rem` }}>Jewish Federation of Greater Philadelphia</h3>
    <p>I was brought on as the technical project manager for the website redesign and migration from Drupal to WordPress. I stayed on as the solo web developer and email marketing manager.</p>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column">
          <h3>Before</h3>
          <JFedOldWebsite />
        </div>
        <div className="column">
          <h3>After</h3>
          <JFedNewWebsite />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <WebDevelopment />
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

When I do, it throws the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'github' of undefined.

Clearly there's something I'm not understanding, and I can't uncover anything in tutorials. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Did you add github token?

Comment: Yes, I did. It just isn't committed to my repo.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly. Do not use links to code; provide a minimal example as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiya it looks like you are using a page query in a component. For component queries you would need to use StaticQuery or the useStaticQuery hook. Check out these docs https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/ & https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/

Comment: Thank you so much for that! That's definitely what I didn't understand. Still having a bit of trouble with rendering the array of values, but much more on the right track.